# Understanding ghidra disassembly

Tags: disassembly, assembly, ghidra

I'm kind of new to assembly and `ghidra` as a tool. I have a question about the meaning of this line

```
Mov dword PTR [ESP] => local_70 , eax
```

I get we are moving `eax` into the left side but I'm not sure what the `[ESP]=>local_70` chunk is as I haven't come across that before. I think the => confuses me the most.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `local_70` is simply a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

I've disassembled one of my programs and it seems that `mem/reg => value` just means that `value` was moved to `mem/reg`.

So, in your example, `mov dword PTR [ESP] => local_70 , eax` is just `mov dword PTR [ESP], eax`, but `Ghidra` knows that the value at `rax` is `local_70` (it was probably set few lines above that instruction), so it displays this information for you.

**Tip:** When in doubt what some particular instruction means, you can right click on that instruction and select `Instruction info...` option to know what it really does.

Comment: `Instruction info...` is going to provide more information on the SLEIGH pieces, but not really what they do.  If you install manuals in correct locations you can `Processor Manual...` which should load to the page

Comment: "but Ghidra knows that the value at rax is local_70" Is that a mistake (shouldn't it be `ESP` instead of `rax`?